# What is this text format?

Tags: text, format

I'm looking to parse a file that has a format like the example below, but I have no idea what format it is. Does anyone know what type of format this is?

The file is actually from a checkpoint firewall backup (objects.c).

```
(
  :mime_types (mime_types
    :mimes (
      : (
        :file_ext (
          : (gif)
        )
        :patterns (
          : (
            :bytes (
              : (
                :mask (FF)
                :offset (0)
                :value (47)
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Thanks

Comment: That's very curious. I googled this syntax and found a bunch of files here (they have extension `.C`): ftp://115.21.116.202/gse/main_db/ . Have a look at objects.C

Comment: yeah, the syntax above actually comes from an objects.c file. I should have mentioned that this is from a Checkpoint firewall backup.

Answer (score 0):

It's a custom config format used by Checkpoint Firewall.

There are unofficial parsers out there, which allow to read and to transform into other formats, like CSV or HTML or firewall config formats of other vendors: **http://www.wyae.de/software/FWtools/**